# Django: within html reference foreign key from user

Tags: django

models.py:

```
class Banking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    available_credits = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

base.html:

```
{{ user.banking.available_credits }}
```

Can I use the user object to reference the available_credits in the banking table?
I'm using this base.html as a template which all other templates extend and ideally don't want to pass the specific instance in. I was hoping there was a way to reference it in a similar way to

`{{ user.username }}`

Comment: Will a user have only one banking or many banking?

Comment: just one banking

Comment: you can add @property in your user model, and refer in template as user.available_credit

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with functions and then pass it to the template

```
 get_available_credits = Banking.objects.filter(user = request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that if each user must only have one banking, one should use  `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey`. This way, `user.banking.something` will work. However, note, that it is still possible that User won't have a banking, and a `Banking.DoesNotExist` will be raised when accessing `user.banking`.